# When I try to rename a favicon in a react project to "favicon.ico" the icon changes to react logo

Tags: reactjs

[before renaming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKZkr.png)

[After renaming same file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gieJO.png)

without naming the file "favicon.ico" is there any other option to add favicon to a react project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that can occur when in development. When building the project, it will load at the new favicon. If that doesn't work the case may be with browser cookies, try erasing your cookies and then the new favicon will show.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the modules being loaded in your client app and see if any are importing the logo:

```html
import logo from '../logo.svg';
```

Your default favicon might be being overridden by the React things

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).